# HyperlinkedIdentityField and null values in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got two models (code is simplified):

```
class Document(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    doc = models.OneToOneField(
              Document,
              blank=True, null=True,
              on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

I would like to make a hyperlink to the Documents details page in the serializer for Item using the HyperlinkedIdentityField.
So I have the URL defined:

```
url(r'^doc/(?P<version>[v1|v2]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
    doc_details,
    name = 'api_document_details'
),
```

And I made the following serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doc = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
                view_name  = 'api_document_details',
                lookup_field = 'doc_id',
                lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'doc')
```

The problem here is that the doc field in Item is optional. I got an `error` as there is no URL to be found if the doc_id = None.

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "api_document_details". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

I would like `HyperlinkedIdentityField` to return None (null) if the document is not defined in the record. Does anybody know how to do this?

I have tried using the `SerializerMethodField()` method in which I use the reverse function and return None if I get an exception, but this has two disadvantages:

1. I cannot see which version is requested, so I default to `v1`
2. It's a relative `url`that is generated, do the domain is not included in the returned value.

Comment: how about `HyperlinkedRelatedField` with `allow_null=True`?

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if you have a reverse relation?

Comment: I'll check later today.